# Repeat a while condition in python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am making a login page in which I have to cover all the login test scenarios. I am am validating all type of input the user is putting, but the problem is when a while condition handles one test condition, that same while condition is not repeated after the another while condition runs.  if the same test condition occurs again after  user puts the same input value after another type of input value. Here is my code:

```
import re
userDetails=[]
accountDetails= {"FirstName": "Ajay", "LastName": "Kumar","DateOfBirth":"24-07-1992","Account Number":"4242342345234","Balance Currency":"Rs","Balance Amount":"5000"}
specialCharacters = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
firstName=str(input("Enter First Name"))

while True:
    if firstName=="":
        print("Name cannot be blank")
        firstName=str(input("Enter First Name"))

while True:
    if firstName.isdigit():
        print("Name cannot be in digits")
        firstName=str(input("Enter First Name"))

while True:
    if specialCharacters.search(firstName) != None:
        print("Please don't enter special characters")
        firstName=str(input("Enter First Name"))

while True:
    if firstName!=accountDetails.get("FirstName"):
        print("The account does not exist with the given details, please try again")
        print("Enter valid first name")
        firstName=str(input("Enter First Name"))

else:
    userDetails.append(firstName)
```

Comment: Add a break function to exit from while loop, or else it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Why don't you put the actual condition you're checking in your `while` statements, instead of `True`?

Answer (score 1):

Use exceptions and functions and do all your validation at once:

```
class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass

def validate_name(name):
    name = name.strip()

    if not name:
        raise ValidationError("Name cannot be blank")

    if name.isdigit():
        raise ValidationErrir("Name cannot be in digits")

    if specialCharacters.search(name) is not None:
        raise ValidationError("Please don't enter special characters")

    if name != accountDetails.get("FirstName"):
        raise ValidationError("The account does not exist with the given details, please try again")


def get_first_name():
    while True:
        first_name = input("Enter First Name")
        try:
            validate_name(firstName)
        except ValidationError as e:
            print(str(e))
        else:
            # ok we're good
            return first_name

first_name = get_first_name()
do_something_with(first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to write it:

```
import re

specialCharacters = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
accountDetails= {"FirstName": "Ajay", "LastName": "Kumar","DateOfBirth":"24-07-1992","Account Number":"4242342345234","Balance Currency":"Rs","Balance Amount":"5000"}

not_valid = True
while not_valid:
    firstName=str(input("Enter First Name: "))
    if firstName == "" or specialCharacters.search(firstName) != None or firstName.isdigit() or firstName!=accountDetails.get("FirstName"):
        not_valid = True
        continue

    else:
        not_valid = False
```

It could also be done with a break.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest refactoring the validation to a separate function, something like this.

```
import re

userDetails = []

accountDetails = {
  "FirstName": "Ajay",
  "LastName": "Kumar",
  "DateOfBirth": "24-07-1992",
  "Account Number": "4242342345234",
  "Balance Currency":"Rs",
  "Balance Amount":"5000",
}

specialCharacters = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')

def validate(accountDetails, firstName):
    if not firstName:
        return "Name cannot be blank"

    if firstName.isdigit():
        return "Name cannot be in digits"

    if specialCharacters.search(firstName):
        return "Please don't enter special characters"

    if firstName != accountDetails.get("FirstName"):
        return "The account does not exist with the given details, please try again"

    return None  # No error

while True:
    firstName = str(input("Enter First Name"))
    error = validate(accountDetails, firstName)
    if error:
        print(error)
    else:
        break

userDetails.append(firstName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how while works, or loops in general. Let's go through your code -

```
firstName=str(input("Enter First Name"))
# We got an input
while True: # (Oh, I have to run indefinitely)
    ....
```

The first `while True` will get you stuck in an infinite loop and the code won't be executed ever after. Rather than doing this, do something like -

```
while not len(firstName): # (Okay, I will run till I get a non empty firstname)
    # your code
# and subsequent conditions 
while not firstName.isdigit():
    # your code

#.... and so on
```

Or better rather, put these `condition`s in a `function`